# Prove a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Show that the polynomial $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ if and only if $n=p$ is a prime. (For the direction when $n=p$, make a change of variable $x\to x+1$ and use Eisenstein criterion).
>
> Extra Credit: If $f$ is an irreducible integral polynomial in $\Bbb Q[x]$, can $f$ be changed, with a change of variable, to something satisfying Eisenstein criterion?

My idea:

For the first part, I tried to prove by contradiction. I assume if there is  $g(x)$ whose degree is less than $n-1$ and $g(x)\mid f(x)$ there must be another polynomial $h(x)$ whose degree is less than $g(x)$ and $h(x)\mid f(x)$. but I still have no idea how to write a complete prove, and can anyone give me a hint for extra credit part?

Thank you all for reading this.

Comment: For the first part: what kind of factors do you always have for $x^{ab}-1$, when $n=ab$ (first multiply your polynomial by $x-1$).

Comment: so (x-1)f(x)=x^(ab)-1?then?

Comment: $x^{ab}-1=(x^a)^b-1=(x^b)^a-1$.

Comment: $x^{rs-1}+x^{rs-2}+...+x+1=(x^{r-1}+x^{r-2}+...+1)(x^{r(s-1)}+x^{r(s-2)}+...+x^{r}+1)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen are you try to prove if p is prime, f(x) must be irreducible?

Comment: No. I'm giving a hint for the other direction: when $n=ab$, $f(x)$ is not irreducible.

Comment: @Ocambole thank you, I think I get you idea, if p is prime, f(X) must be irreducible.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I get it!

Comment: For the $p$ prime case the advice in the exercise is to substitute $x\to x+1$ and use Eisenstein. To that end it also helps to think of $f(x)$ as $(x^n-1)/(x-1)$. What I was hinting at was spelled out by Ocambole.

Comment: thank you for your guys, I am a little confuse about the extra credit part, if a polynomial is already irreducible over Q, can we make it reducible by change of variable? it sounds impossible to me.@JyrkiLahtonen @Ocambole

Comment: @DanialJeo An invertible change of variable can't make the polynomial reducible; but it could make it into a polynomial satisfying Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @egreg ok, it is getting interesting.